# Parameterized queries in Google App Engine Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, prepared-statement

The GAE Datastore provides a class `PreparedQuery`, which is the compiled form of a query.  But is there such a thing as a parameterized query (e.g. `lastname = {?}`) ?  There’s no point in compiling a query if it needs to be recompiled every time a parameter changes (unless the same exact query is run over and over again, in which case its results should be cached, anyway).

Did I overlook something in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't - parameters are specified when you construct the Query object. 'Preparing' a query is not an expensive operation, however - no datastore roundtrips are involved.